# Mapping string characters to vector

Tags: c++

Please tell me what is the problem in this approach of mapping string characters to vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void strTOvec(string x, vector<string> y) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x.c_str()); i++) {
    y.push_back(x[i]);
  }
}

void main() {}
```

Received errors: E0304, C2664, C4018

Comment: First step would be to read and understand the actual text of the error messages and not the error numbers. Then try to figure what that message means in the context of the line indicated to be the position of the problem. Looking up the error number in the MSDN (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4018 ) can also help understand what is going on.

Comment: First of all, main should return int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors.

- `main` must return an `int`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function
- argument `string x` will unnecessarily copy your `string` (if you don't move the argument when calling your function)
- as you are trying to copy each `char` of the `std::string` into a `std::vector`, your `std::vector` should be `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::vector<std::string>` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)
- if you really need to use `std::vector<std::string>`, you need to convert your `char` to `std::string`. There are many ways of doing so. Modifying your loop this way would allow this:

  `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x.c_str()); i++)
      y.push_back({x[i]});`
- `vector<string> y` will also create a copy. I guess you are looking for something like `std::vector<char>&` (note the `&`, and if you don't know what it means: https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference)
- your `for` loop is valid (if your vector `y` is of type `std::vector<char>`)
- using a function with return type `void` which modifies an argument passed by reference is not modern C++. Maybe you would prefer to return a `std::vector<char>` instead?
- check this way of copying the characters of a string into a vector of chars:

  `std::vector<char> y(x.begin(),x.end());`
- do your research, use cppreference, ...

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector<std::string>` doesn't contain single characters as elements, but `std::string` objects. A `std::string` object is always a sequence of characters, you can't construct a `std::string` from one single character using direct initialization. But this is what you're trying to do:

```
y.push_back(x[i]);
//          ^^^^ returns a reference to the i-th character in the string
```

You either want to change the vector instantiation into `std::vector<char>`, hence the function signature would be

```
void strTOvec(string x, vector<char> y)
```

or you might keep the vector type and use list initialization:

```
y.push_back({x[i]});
//          ^    ^ Note the additional braces
```

Both options reflect completely different behavior though. The first adds every character in `x` to a vector or single characters, the second turns every chacter in `x` into a new `string` object of length 1 and adds this one to the vector.

Note also that `main` must return an `int`. Special rule here: you don't have to return it explicitly. So changing the `main` function to

```
int main() {}
```

is sufficient, while an additional `return 0;` doesn't hurt.

Comment: You can construct a `std::string` from one single character: https://ideone.com/AR0ovt

Comment: @mch Thanks, I forgot about list initialization. Will fix.